# Update node key index in batch operation

Tags: neo4j

### Short

I can't get neo to update existing node properties in a batched rest op.

### Long

I want to create a batch operation that inserts/updates a node inside an index. It should handle three use-cases:

1. if the node does not exist, insert it with the given properties set
2. if the node exists, update it's properties set with the new values, if any.

I'm using the batch operation api, I wrote a test where I'm issuing two requests:
Short
1. first one inserts the node and indexes it's properties
2. second one simply updates some properties of the node

Here's the first request:

> [
>       {
>           "method": "POST",
>           "to": "/index/node/events?uniqueness=get_or_create",
>           "id": 1,
>           "body": {
>               "key": "id",
>               "value": "222222222",
>               "properties": {
>                   "id": "222222222",
>                   "type": "event-type"
>               }
>           }
>       },
>       {
>           "method": "POST",
>           "to": "/index/node/events",
>           "body": {
>               "uri": "{1}",
>               "key": "id",
>               "value": "222222222"
>           }
>       },
>       {
>           "method": "POST",
>           "to": "/index/node/events",
>           "body": {
>               "uri": "{1}",
>               "key": "type",
>               "value": "event-type"
>           }
>       } ]

And now the second one.

> [
>       {
>           method: 'POST',
>           to: '/index/node/events?uniqueness=get_or_create',
>           id: 1,
>           body: {
>               key: 'id',
>               value: '222222222',
>               properties: {id: '222222222', type: 'event-type', title: 'SUPEREVENT'}
>           }
>       },
>       {
>           method: 'POST',
>           to: '/index/node/events',
>           body: {
>               uri: '{1}',
>               key: 'id',
>               value: '222222222'
>           }
>       },
>       {
>           method: 'POST',
>           to: '/index/node/events',
>           body: {
>               uri: '{1}',
>               key: 'type',
>               value: 'event-type'
>           }
>       },
>       {
>           method: 'POST',
>           to: '/index/node/events',
>           body: {
>               uri: '{
>                   1
>               }',
>               key: 'title',
>               value: 'SUPEREVENT'
>           }
>       }
>   ]

NOTE! that on the second request i'm adding and event `title` property with value `SUPEREVENT`. This does not get persisted nor indexed. Why? and how can I fix it?

Thank you,
Alex

Comment: sorry about the json indenting (or lack there of), i can't get it to auto-indent in SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the doc:

> URL Parameter uniqueness=get_or_create: Create a new node/relationship
>   and index it if no existing one can be found. If an existing
>   node/relationship is found, discard the sent data and return the
>   existing node/relationship.

So your second request's data will be discarded. You need to split each of your requests in two requests each, and do two batches. Each of the two batches has two instructions: first one creates the node if not present, and the second one updates the properties.